# owl carousel : first slide not trigger action

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I'm trying do a food menu with owl carousel, but on first slide actions are not triggering, if I press next button it will go to next slide works fine, by pressing previous button can come to main menu and flow is works fine main menu start clickable, only when its load main menu not triggering any action. By pressing next any previous works fine.

http://globalsolutions.work/twin4/main-menu/staters/index.html

How to trigger action after page load, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

if you follow the basic structure of owl carousel then this type of problem will now appear
you can check this documentation form here or still you facing the issue please add your code https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html